# Projecting to another type using the C# SDK

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to be able to project to *another* type when querying MongoDB using the C# SDK.

For example, below I want to query the collection using builder filters (or LINQ expressions) for `MyType`, **but** I want to project the result to `MySubType`.

```
var mySubTypes = Database
    .GetCollection<MyType>("MyCollection")
    .Find(Builders<MyType>.Filter.AnyIn(x => x.Documents, documentId))
    .ProjectTo<MySubType>() // Project to another type??
    .ToList();
```

One could imagine `MySubType` to be a subset of `MyType`, represented using inheritance:

```
public class MyType : MySubType
{
    [BsonElement("documents")]
    public List<string> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class MySubType
{
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Why do I want to do this?**

Because the `Documents` array is very large and used purely during querying (i.e. to filter) within the database engine. Retrieving and serializing this array will be an unnecessary cost.

Comment: Sounds like you want Cast<T>() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @fhlamarche: No, since I need the projection to happen within the database engine and not on client side.

Comment: Could you give us a sample DataSet and the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the way to execute mapping you want:

```
collection
    .Find(Builders<MyType>.Filter.AnyIn(x => x.Documents, new[] { "c" }))
    .Project(Builders<MyType>.Projection.Exclude(c => c.Documents))
    .As<MySubType>()
    .ToList();
```

But first you should register mapping for your SubType with ignoring extra element. I don't understand it 100%, seems to be a bug of the driver, it doesn't get `Documents` from mongo, but knows, that `MyType` has such property. Note, you should register your class mapping, **before** you first create collection of this type.

```
if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(MySubType)))
{
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MySubType>(cm =>
    {
        cm.AutoMap();
        cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
    });
}
```

I did it with sample data :

```
var toInsert = new List<MyType>
{
    new MyType {Id = 1, Name = "bla", Documents =new List<string> {"a", "b", "v"}},
    new MyType {Id = 2, Name = "ada", Documents =new List<string> {"c", "d", "r"}},
};
```

And  could get the expected  output:

```
collection
    .Find(Builders<MyType>.Filter.AnyIn(x => x.Documents, new[] { "c" }))
    .Project(Builders<MyType>.Projection.Exclude(c => c.Documents))
    .As<MySubType>()
    .ToList()
    .Dump();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. In addition, I wrote an extension method to exclude all the relevant properties implicitly (using reflection).

Comment: Disadvantage of this is, that the projection will be done server side in memory, rather than database side. It doesn't limit the data sent through the wire.