# MongoDB.net driver - project into different class

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

When trying to project a typed document into a different class, I get the following: **Could not find a member match for constructor parameter *"origItem"* on type *"NewItem"* in the expression tree new NewItem({document}, 1021).**

A simplified example of the classes are as follows:

```
public class OriginalItem
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<double> Data { get; set; }
    
    public OriginalItem() { }
}
public class NewItem
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    
    public NewItem() { }
    public NewItem( OriginalItem origItem, int targetIdx )
    {
        Id = origItem.Id;
        Name = origItem.Name;
        Value = origItem.Data[targetIdx];
    }
}
```

An example of where the issue occurs is as follows:

```
IList<ObjectId> ids; // list of OriginalItem Ids to get
IMongoCollection<OriginalItem> collection = _db.GetCollection<OriginalItem>("items");
int targetIdx = 50;

IList<NewItem> newItems = await collection.Aggregate()
                         .Match( item => ids.Contains( item.Id ) )
                         .Project( origItem => new NewItem( origItem, targetIdx ) )
                         .ToListAsync();
```

I looked around and it seems like [my only option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41963211/projecting-to-another-type-using-the-c-sharp-sdk) would be project & transform the the *origItem* into a BsonDocument, and deserialize that into a *NewItem*. I've also tested changing `new NewItem( origItem, targetIdx )` to `new NewItem { //... }` works.

I know I can simply read the item and perform the necessary transformations outside of the mongo server, but the real use case is slightly more complicated and I would like to at least figure out what I'm failing to understand.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have run into this issue as well. After scouring the internet for a while, I finally found that using the `Builder`'s `Project.Expression` method was the only way that worked. For your scenario it would result in something like the following

```cs
var project = Builders<OriginalItem>.Projection.Expression(item => new NewItem(origItem, targetInx));

IList<NewItem> newItems = await collection.Aggregate()
                         .Match( item => ids.Contains( item.Id ) )
                         .Project(project)
                         .ToListAsync();
```

I also removed all of the constructor logic, and instead had it doing straight assignments. So instead of
`new NewItem(origItem, targetInx)` you would end up with something like `new NewItem(item.Id, item.Name, item.Data[targetIdx])`. I'm not certain if this step is necessary, but if the above doesn't work then I would definitely try this as well.

Comment: Disadvantage of this approach, is that this does not limit the data sent over the wire. Projection is done server side.